# How to create x-labels in this xbar

Tags: r, qcc

I am using the `qcc` library to create an xbar.

When I use the following values it works:

```
data <- c(4.74, 8.71, 7.01)
qcc(data, type="xbar.one", center = 2)
```

I however also want to plot values on the x-axis. So instead of saying 1, 2, 3 it should say: "John, Mike, Jason"

Any thoughts on how I can easily add these values on the x-axis?

Comment: you can just use the `labels` argument of the function : `qcc(data, type="xbar.one", center = 2, labels=c("John", "Mike", "Jason"))` (it might have helped to have a look at `help("qcc")`...)

Comment: Thanks @CathG. Will dive into the help funtion next time. Just a starter

Comment: tutorials and help pages are better (and more appropriate) than SO to start..